# positioning font awesome icon to scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I'm having some trouble positioning a font-awesome icon. What I want to happen is for the down arrow to fade out when the user scrolls to the bottom of the document and the up arrow to fade in. When the user scrolls to the top of the document, I want the up arrow to fade out and the down arrow to fade in.

I believe I need to position the up and down arrows on top of one another so there isn't a "jump" effect when one fades out and the other fades in. However, when I try to position the arrows absolutely, the whole parent div disappears. Can anyone tell what's happening?

html:

```
<div id="arrowholder">
    <div class="scroll">SCROLL</div>
    <i id="down" class="fa fa-4x fa-angle-down"></i>
    <i id="up" class="fa fa-4x fa-angle-up"></i>
</div>
```

css:

```
#arrowholder {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    text-align: center;
 bottom: 0px;

}
.scroll {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
#down {
    display: block;
    /*position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);*/
    z-index: 5;
}
#up {
    display: none;
    /*position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);*/
    z-index: 2;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
           $( "#down" ).fadeOut();
           $( "#up" ).fadeIn();

       }
       //var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        //console.log(scrollTop);
        var topDistance = $('#up').offset().top;
        if ( topDistance <= height ) {
            $( "#up" ).fadeOut();
            $( "#down" ).fadeIn();

        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead of `fadeIn/Out`, using `opacity` because the `fadeIn/Out` make the element to `display:block/none` which make the effect of "jumping"

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
    $("#down").animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 100);
    $("#up").animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 100);
  }
  //var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  //console.log(scrollTop);
  var topDistance = $('#up').offset().top;
  if (topDistance <= $(window).height()) {
    $("#down").animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 100);
    $("#up").animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 100);

  }
});
```

```css
#arrowholder {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
}
.scroll {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 53%;
  transform: translate(-53%);
}
#up {
  opacity: 0
}
#up,
#down {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus quis sem sed eros dignissim aliquam at non massa. Integer placerat enim eros, quis condimentum dui malesuada nec. Integer sagittis facilisis laoreet. Vivamus mattis luctus tellus, at ullamcorper
  lacus ultricies id. Cras sagittis, erat vitae cursus pulvinar, eros libero pulvinar nisl, vitae ultricies nulla velit in lectus. Nulla a eros vel mi tincidunt interdum. Aliquam volutpat porta arcu eget viverra. Maecenas a porta nulla, ac fermentum est.
  Aliquam convallis molestie magna et accumsan. Phasellus lacinia aliquet est et pretium. Nullam in ex suscipit nunc pulvinar elementum. Pellentesque pulvinar libero cursus, suscipit dui vel, viverra urna. Nulla ut justo luctus, porttitor magna non, suscipit
  eros. Etiam pharetra porttitor diam, at congue eros efficitur in. Proin porta sagittis sem. Vivamus ut ullamcorper magna. Aliquam pulvinar eleifend augue, sit amet semper libero vulputate ut. Phasellus dapibus mauris eget risus fringilla, at vulputate
  dolor vehicula. Etiam at turpis ac arcu bibendum facilisis. Aliquam at magna tortor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent rutrum, nibh dignissim ultricies dapibus, mi erat elementum diam, ac
  mattis felis metus et sem. Quisque hendrerit odio quis venenatis tempor. Cras id elit ultricies purus ultricies facilisis sagittis quis ipsum. Donec condimentum risus mauris, nec blandit libero feugiat eget. Cras nisl dolor, rhoncus accumsan lacinia
  ac, elementum non arcu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur sit amet ullamcorper velit, vitae faucibus felis. Ut nec sem pellentesque, laoreet velit a, imperdiet nulla. Integer viverra rhoncus ligula ac commodo. Etiam
  justo purus, lacinia non lectus vulputate, hendrerit iaculis lorem. Praesent condimentum odio sapien, vitae lacinia enim facilisis sit amet. Aenean vehicula fringilla pretium. Quisque est magna, venenatis a nisi eget, ultricies tincidunt velit. Mauris
  nibh tellus, tempor vel libero nec, suscipit sagittis augue. Nam id luctus lacus. Proin sit amet orci mollis, rhoncus orci in, vehicula enim. Aenean a odio non justo auctor hendrerit eu et mi. Curabitur eu augue neque. Donec bibendum felis vel nibh
  viverra iaculis. Duis rhoncus elementum mauris. Nam ac magna ex. Quisque sodales vitae libero vitae tincidunt. Nulla pretium cursus hendrerit. Aliquam ut varius nisl. Phasellus nec ipsum pharetra, tempus lectus vel, gravida arcu. Donec non semper ipsum,
  eu sagittis leo. Vestibulum a leo mollis, malesuada mauris quis, facilisis mauris. Nam purus sem, pulvinar lacinia dui eu, scelerisque placerat odio. Proin egestas quis sem et fringilla. Ut convallis ipsum tortor, in luctus odio mattis a.</div>
<div id="arrowholder">
  <div class="scroll">SCROLL</div>
  <i id="down" class="fa fa-4x fa-angle-down"></i>
  <i id="up" class="fa fa-4x fa-angle-up"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: @LauraNMS what you don't know what works? I explained the `animate()`, what else do you need me to explain to you? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, and change the z-index of #down to higher to enable click actions over #up.

```
#up {
    visibility:hidden;
    margin-top:-64px;
    display: block;
    /*position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);*/
    z-index: 2;
}
```